# How to get parent keys from JSON using JSEL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using JSEL (https://github.com/dragonworx/jsel) for search data in a huge JSON. This is an extract:

```
{
 "Clothes":[{
    "id":"clothes",
    "items":[{
        "shoes":[{
            "sizes":{
                "S":{
                    "cod":"S1"
                },
                "M":{
                    "cod":"M1"
                },
                "L":{
                    "cod":"L1"
                }
            }
        }],
        "pants":[{
            "sizes":{
                "S":{
                    "cod":"PS1"
                },
                "M":{
                    "cod":"PM1"
                },
                "L":{
                    "cod":"L1"
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
 }]
}
```

If I execute this command:

```
var dom = jsel(data);
console.log( dom.selectAll('//@cod') );
```

I obtain an array with all "cod" key values from JSON:

```
['S1', 'M1', 'L1', 'PS1', 'PM1', 'L1']
```

I'm newbie on XPath expressions and I want to get the parent keys of a certain "cod" key value, for example, if "cod" key value is "S1" the result is:

```
"shoes"
```

or

```
"items"
```

or

```
"Clothes"
```

How can I get it? I'd like to receive your help

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways available in JS. I usually prefer this kind it's more quick and reusable in any kind of objects.
You can try below snippet and you will get it more clear.

```js
var jsonString = '{"Clothes":[{"id":"clothes", "items":[{"shoes":[{"sizes":{"S":{"cod":"S1"}, "M":{"cod":"M1"}, "L":{"cod":"L1"} } }], "pants":[{"sizes":{"S":{"cod":"PS1"}, "M":{"cod":"PM1"}, "L":{"cod":"L1"} } }] }] }] }';
const myObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
for (let i in myObj.Clothes) {
    var clothes = myObj.Clothes[i];
    var clothesId = clothes.id;
    var clothesItems = clothes.items;
    console.log(clothesId);

    var products = Object.keys(clothesItems[0])
    for( var productName in products ){
        var productName = products[productName];
        var productSizes = clothesItems[0][productName][0].sizes;
        console.log(productName);
        console.log(productSizes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems generic, what I want is obtain all the parent keys if I search a certain “cod” key value.